# How to lower the number of MySQL queries using Object Oriented Code

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Let's take a simple example:
I have products. Products can be in 1 or many Categories, and also in 1 or many Channels.

So I have an object for Product, Category and Channel, as well as their mapper and factory classes.

My approach #1 is to be 100% decoupled; the ProductFactory just create an instance of a Product. And inside the Product classe, I have lazy instanciation method that call the Category & Channel Factory and store the objet as needed.

That's great for the product Details Page, but when it come to a product listing, my query count gets really high, as I must do 2 extra query per product, and let's face it: when I display the list of the products in the category #2, it's completly insane to instanciate 25 time the very same category for each product.

My approach #2 is to couple things a little bit; the ProductFactory make some JOIN and fetch all the informations of the Category and Channel, and instanciate them. IMO that's as much nasty as the first solution, because it the query count get low, I just run bigger query, so in the background, it changes nothing.

My approach #3 is to keep thing decoupled, but have no chainable automatisation; I would first loop over all the product, and make an array of all the Category and all the Channel, control duplicate ID, and then instanciate all of them. That seem nice, but the code is no more chainable. ( Ie.: I can't do $product->getCategory() to get the list of the category where the product is stored.)

What approach do you suggest ?

Comment: One big query isn't equivalent to several smaller queries - each query adds overhead, so you are actually better off if you can combine them.

Comment: You're right, but I was more thinking about the fact that I'm fetching 25 time the very same information...

Answer (score 1):

What if you keep an array in the format

```
CATEGORY_ID => CATEGORY_OBJECT
```

Then when you need to assign a category you can check that array first. For example:

```
$page_categories = array();

foreach( $products as $product ) {
    if ( isset( $page_categories[$product->category_id] ) ) {
        $product->category =  $page_categories[$product->category_id];
    }
    else {
        $product->category = $page_categories[$product->category_id] = new Category( $product->category_id );
    }
}
```